# Java driver equivalent for JavaScript shell's Object.bsonsize( doc )?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I was wondering what the Java driver's equivalent to the Mongo JavaScript shell's Object.bsonsize( doc ) method?  For example, what is the Java code to perform the following:

```
bobk-mbp:~ bobk$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: test
PRIMARY> use devices;
switched to db devices
PRIMARY> Object.bsonsize( db.profiles.findOne( { _id: "REK_0001" } ) );
186
PRIMARY> Object.bsonsize( db.profiles.findOne( { _id: "REK_0002" } ) );
218
PRIMARY>
```

How do I perform this same basic use case with the MongoDB Java Driver.  Its not obvious through the JavaDocs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing quite as clean as what's available in the shell, but this will work:

```
DBObject obj = coll.findOne();
int bsonSize = DefaultDBEncoder.FACTORY.create().
        writeObject(new BasicOutputBuffer(), obj));
```

Comment: Wow.  That is long winded, and I can't resolve any DefaultDBEncoder in my IDE using Mongo 2.6.5 Java driver.  Its also undesirable to have to write the document to figure out its size.  My actual use case is I'm trying to enforce some size limits before I commit a document to the database.  In any event, thanks for the reply and I'll see if I can get there from here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [BasicBSONEncoder](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/BasicBSONEncoder.html):

```
DBObject obj = coll.findOne();
int bsonSize = new BasicBSONEncoder().encode(obj).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
        CommandResult result = db.doEval("Object.bsonsize(db.profiles.findOne({ _id: "REK_0001" }))");
        double bsonSize = (Double) result.get("retval");
```

It's double instead of int.

*doEval* is part of the MongoDB Java Driver since the first version.